# Trying to figure out how to resolve IE's document.frames["someframe"].function in Chrome

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer, google-chrome

I have some code that works in IE.

```
try{
   top.document.frames["myFrame"].compare();
}catch(err){
   alert("This is not executed.");
}
```

which doesn't work in Chrome.  How should i resolve it?  I was thinking that you could do some thing such as

```
top.document.frames["myFrame"].compare() || /*google chrome variant*/ ;
```

Thanks gang! :)

Oh, what i am doing is selecting the frame "myFrame" and executing a function inside of said frame.

Edit:   Added jQuery as a tag because there might be a way to do it that way as well

**Edit:** -  the caught error in my example is:

```
TypeError:  Cannot read property of "myFrame" of undefined
```

Comment: What is the error message?

Comment: have you tried `top.document.getElementById('myFrame');`? I believe `document.frames` is unsupported.

Comment: using the Chrome debugger, doing top.document.getElementById("myFrame").someFunction() does not work.  Standby for error information

Comment: is someFunction defined on the iframe node? that would be an obvious reason for it to not work.

Comment: Yes, it is.  It works in IE just fine, but not in Chrome.  My thought is that standards are not carried over, but i am looking to find a way such that it works cross platform.

Comment: this is what's failing by the way(based on the given error message): `top.document.frames` `.frames` doesn't exist on `top.document` you can solve it by using another method to get to the frame, such as getting it by id or name.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The standard way to do that is this one:

```
window.frames["yourFrame"].yourFunction();
```

Comment: This indeed works.  Though i am curious.... How would i do it for nesting frames in frames incase i run into it in the future?
  window.frames["frameA"].window.frames["frameB"].yourFunction();   ?

Comment: window.frames["frameA"].frames["frameB"].yourFunction();

Comment: getting the facts straight, there is no public standard that applies to the Window object, but all major browsers support it.